Access env object inside config file in Strapi
In strapi, how can I retrieve the env variables from a config file. I have two config files: one to handle rabbitmq connection rabbitmq, and one to handle the topics and sending of message topics.ts. I use env variables in my rabbitmq such as the URL of the rabbitmq connection:
import amqp, { Channel, Connection, Options } from 'amqplib';
import { Topic, Message } from './topics';

export default ({ env }) => {
  let connection: Connection | null = null;
  let channel: Channel | null = null;

  const INGEST_QUEUE = env('RABBITMQ_INGEST_QUEUE', 'spring-boot-queue');
  const RABBITMQ_URL = env('RABBITMQ_URL', 'amqp://user:password@localhost:5672');
  const RECONNECT_INTERVAL = env.int('RABBITMQ_RECONNECT_INTERVAL', 3000);

  const connect = async (): Promise<void> => {
    if (connection) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      connection = await amqp.connect(RABBITMQ_URL);
      channel = await connection.createChannel();
      console.log('Connected to RabbitMQ!');
      connection.on('close', handleConnectionClose);
      connection.on('error', handleConnectionError);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to RabbitMQ', error);
      setTimeout(connect, RECONNECT_INTERVAL);
    }
  };
  
  const handleConnectionClose = (): void => {
    console.warn('RabbitMQ connection closed. Reconnecting...');
    connection = null;
    channel = null;
    setTimeout(connect, RECONNECT_INTERVAL);
  };
  
  const handleConnectionError = (error: any): void => {
    console.error('RabbitMQ connection error', error);
    connection?.close();
  };
  
  const assertExchange = async (topic: Topic): Promise<void> => {
    if (!channel) {
      throw new Error('Channel is not initialized');
    }
    await channel.assertExchange(topic, 'topic', { durable: false });
  };
  
  const sendMessageToQueue = async (topic: Topic, message: Message): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      if (!channel) {
        await connect();
      }
      await assertExchange(topic);
      channel.sendToQueue(INGEST_QUEUE, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message)), {
        contentType: 'application/json'
      } as Options.Publish);
      console.log(`Message sent to queue: ${INGEST_QUEUE} with topic: ${topic}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to send message to queue', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  return {
    connect,
    sendMessageToQueue,
  };
};

And I need to initiate this "object" to be used in my topics.ts class or elsewhere, but unfortunately I don't have access to the strapi object
import rabbitmq from "./rabbitmq";

const poop = rabbitmq({env: ""});

export enum Topic {
    Product = "Product",
    Inventory = "Inventory",
}

export enum MessageType {
    Upsert = "Upsert",
    Delete = "Delete"
}

export interface Message {
    data: any,
    topic: Topic,
    type: MessageType
}

const buildMessage = (data: any, topic: Topic, type: MessageType): Message => {
    return {
        data,
        topic,
        type
    }
}

type Caster<T> = (result: any) => T;

export const handleEvent = <T>(event: any, messageType: MessageType, cast: Caster<T>, topic: Topic) => {
    const { result } = event;
    console.log(`[*] Handling event ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    const data = cast(result);
    const message = buildMessage(data, topic, messageType);
    console.log(`[*] Published ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
    poop.sendMessageToQueue(topic, message);
};

